# Is possible to change sidebar color when using AdminLTE template?

Tags: bootstrap-4, colors, background, sidebar, adminlte

I'm using AdminLTE version 3.2 template and I want to change the color on the sidebar of the template. Is that possible? I mean except dark and light color

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's very possible you just need to change the original css file from its AdminLTE according to your needs.

Comment: I have tried changing on the original css file and I have changed it like this
`.layout-navbar-fixed .wrapper .sidebar-dark-primary .brand-link:not([class*="navbar"]) {
  background-color: #DD7C0A !important;
}` 
but it doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

you can change it with it's given class or custom style

sidebar-dark-primary is responsible for changing the background color of the sidebar

```
<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4"
```

with custom style

```
<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4" style="background-color: green">
```

or

```
<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4" style="background-color: #ffff">
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it at https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/issues/1164.

> It will change if you add !important like: .main-sidebar {
> background-color: #333 !important }.

Change the color value as you desire.